# Need to take infinite sum of residues, is there a way to choose the order of operations for ReleaseHold?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, summation, hold

I'm computing an infinite sum of residues. I want to do something like this:

```
Sum[Sum[(-1)^n (2 π I) Residue[(w^(I nu + n/2) ws^(I nu - n/2))/(I nu + n/2)^2, {nu, I n/2 + I m}], {n, 1, ∞}], {m, 0, ∞}]
```

Evaluated like that, this gives zero. However, if I choose a specific value of m, specifically m=0,

```
Sum[(-1)^n (2 π I) Residue[(w^(I nu + n/2) ws^(I nu - n/2))/(I nu + n/2)^2, {nu, I n/2}], {n, 1, ∞}]
```

I get a nonzero result. The problem is that for generic m,

```
Sum[(-1)^n (2 π I) Residue[(w^(I nu + n/2) ws^(I nu - n/2))/(I nu + n/2)^2, {nu, I n/2 + I m }], {n, 1, ∞}]
```

is zero. It's only nonzero for $m=0$.

I thought that I could make this work by using `Hold`, holding evaluation of the residue and releasing it outside the infinite sum. But it appears that applying `ReleaseHold` there doesn't fix the problem, it still evaluates the Residue for the generic case before fitting in the specific ones.

Is there a way to make this work, and get the correct answer out of the infinite sum over `m`?

(By the way, I know that in this case, all terms besides $m=0$ will be zero. I need the infinite sum because the same setup needs to treat cases where some of those terms are nonzero.)

Comment: I would say it's a bug.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say it's a bug, Mathematica just has a fixed way it handles order of operations. But there should be a way around it, no?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `Residue` (and `Series` on which it is based) is unable to analyze all the cases in which the formula for the residue might vary.  `Reduce` can do it, within its limitations, if we reduce the system `1/function == 0 && nu == pole`.

Here's the OP's example.

```
fn = (w^(n/2 + I nu) ws^(-(n/2) + I nu))/(n/2 + I nu)^2;
```

We need to add some conditions on the system.  The result has an unnecessary complication of `C[1]`, but we can deduce that the only cases for which there is a pole is `m == 0 && n >= 0`:

```
Reduce[1/fn == 0 && nu == I n/2 + I m &&
  m >= 0 && m ∈ Integers && n >= 1 && n ∈ Integers && w != 0 && ws != 0,
 {m, n, nu, w, ws}]
(*
  C[1] ∈ Integers && w != 0 && ws != 0 && C[1] >= 1 && m == 0 &&
    n == C[1] && nu == (I n)/2
*)
```

Hence we need just one sum:

```
Block[{m = 0}, Sum[(-1)^n (2 π I) Residue[fn, {nu, I n/2 + I m}], {n, 1, ∞}]]
(*  -((2 (π Log[w] + π Log[ws]))/(1 + ws))  *)
```

Here's another, albeit similar, example with two special values of `m`.

```
fn2 = (w^(n/2 + I nu) ws^(-(n/2) + I nu))/((n/2 + I nu)^2 (2 + n/2 + I nu)^2);

Reduce[1/fn2 == 0 && nu == I n/2 + I m &&
  m >= 0 && m ∈ Integers && n >= 1 && n ∈ Integers && w != 0 && ws != 0,
 {m, n, nu, w, ws}]
(*
  C[1] ∈ Integers && w != 0 && ws != 0 && C[1] >= 1 &&
     ((m == 0 && n == C[1] && nu == (I n)/2) ||
      (m == 2 && n == C[1] && nu == -(1/2) I (-4 - n)))
*)
```

We can see that there are two cases, `m == 0 && n >= 1` and `m == 2 && n >= 1`.

```
Block[{m = 0}, Sum[(-1)^n (2 π I) Residue[fn2, {nu, I n/2 + I m}], {n, 1, ∞}]]
Block[{m = 2}, Sum[(-1)^n (2 π I) Residue[fn2, {nu, I n/2 + I 2}], {n, 1, ∞}]]
(*
  (π - π Log[w] - π Log[ws])/(2 (1 + ws))
  (-π - π Log[w] - π Log[ws])/(2 w^2 ws^2 (1 + ws))
*)
```

Add these to get the sum over all `m >= 0`.

If all the use-cases exhibit the same pattern, one could write code to process the results of `Reduce` and set up the summations.

Comment: Note: This later question has some of the same problems with the summand behaving differently on generic input: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78945/strange-evaluation-of-an-sum-involving-binomial-coefficients/85630#85630