# Strange evaluation of an sum involving binomial coefficients

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, kernel

I stumbled upon this problem while playing with *Mathematica* 10. Can anyone help me explain the following behaviour?

I define a sum

```
f[m_] := 
  Sum[
    Binomial[m - 1, r] Binomial[r, a] Binomial[m - r - 1, b] 
      z^(r + b) (-1)^(a + b + r + 1), 
    {r, 0, m - 1}, {a, 0, r}, {b, 0, m - r - 1}]
```

Now evaluating `f[3]` gives `-(-1 + z)^2` after simplifying. However, evaluating `f[m]` for unassigned `m` gives `0`, but I expected `(-1)^m (-1 + z)^(m - 1)`. I traced the computation with

```
Trace[f[m]]
```

and the trace returned a list of evaluations which only makes a rearrangement of the sum into canonical form; that is, the last two elements in the trace output are simply my defined sum expression in canonical form followed by `0`. I am pretty confused by *Mathematica's* final evaluation to `0`.

Edit: corrected a typo `-(-1 + z)^(m - 1)` to `(-1)^m (-1 + z)^(m - 1)`.

Comment: Isn't the right answer $(-1)^{m}(-1+z)^{(m-1)}$?

Comment: You are right. Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: Seems to be a bug?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a little like [Need to take infinite sum of residues, is there a way to choose the order of operations for ReleaseHold?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39627/need-to-take-infinite-sum-of-residues-is-there-a-way-to-choose-the-order-of-ope).
It also reminds me a little of [Why does Mathematica simplify $x/x\to1$?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57489/why-does-mathematica-simplify-x-x-to1), in which the symbolic result is generically true.

#### Analysis

The method used in the sum is

```
Method -> "IteratedSummation"
```

so we can examine the major steps:

```
Sum[
 Binomial[m - 1, r] Binomial[r, a] Binomial[m - r - 1, b] z^(r + b) (-1)^(a + b + r + 1),
 {b, 0, m - r - 1}]
Sum[%, {a, 0, r}]
Sum[%, {r, 0, m - 1}]
(*
  ((-1)^(2 + a + r) (1 - z)^(m - r) z^r Binomial[-1 + m, r] Binomial[r, a])/(-1 + z)
  0
  0
*)
```

The second result is a bit mysterious as fundamentally the sum is equivalent to

```
Sum[(-1)^a const Binomial[r, a], {a, 0, r}]
(*  const KroneckerDelta[r]  *)
```

which is no problem.  So *Mathematica*, at some point, must not be able to disentangle the constants from the important factors.  We can try simplifying it.  Each of these yields `0`.

```
Sum[(-1)^(2 + a + r) (1 - z)^(m - r) z^r Binomial[-1 + m, r] Binomial[r, a] /.
   (1 - z)^(m - r) z^r -> u,
 {a, 0, r}]
Sum[(-1)^(2 + a + r) (1 - z)^(m - r)(*z^r*) Binomial[-1 + m, r] Binomial[r, a] /.
   (1 - z)^(m - r) z^r -> u,
 {a, 0, r}]
```

Curiously each of the following yields a correct result, unfortunately in terms of `HypergeometricPFQ`.  The first one is quite similar to last one above.  It's unfortunate in that if we plug them back into `Sum` to complete the calculation, `Sum` returns unevaluated.  Strictly speaking the `HypergeometricPFQ` term is only equivalent to `KroneckerDelta[r]` if `r` is an integer and `r >= 0`; but *Mathematica* seems not to be able to do that transformation.

```
Sum[(-1)^(2 + a + r)(*(1-z)^(m-r)*)z^r Binomial[-1 + m, r] Binomial[r, a],
 {a, 0, r}]
Sum[(-1)^(2 + a + r) (1 - z)^(m - r) z^r Binomial[-1 + m, r] Binomial[r, a] /.
   (1 - z)^(m - r) z^r -> u[r],
 {a, 0, r}]
(*
  (-1)^r z^r Binomial[-1 + m, r] HypergeometricPFQ[{-r}, {}, 1]
  (-1)^r Binomial[-1 + m, r] HypergeometricPFQ[{-r}, {}, 1] u[r]
*)
```

#### Working around the limitations

One workaround is to wrap the constants up in a nice package as a single constant.  The the summation will be computed correctly.  One could also factor the constants out of the sum, such as is done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21007/how-to-simplify-a-complicated-sum-in-terms-of-power-sums/21023#21023) (or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64422/how-to-do-algebra-on-unsolved-integrals/64447#64447) on `Integrate` instead of `Sum`).

We can make a `Hold`-like wrapper, do the sum, and release the hold.  I decided not to use `Hold` itself, because `ReleaseHold` might release other instances of `Hold` that happen to be there.

```
SetAttributes[const`hold, HoldAll];
holdConstants[expr_, v_] := Module[{factors, constants, summand},
  factors = Replace[
     expr,
     s_Times :> FactorList /@ List @@ s] // 
    Flatten@Apply[Power, #, {2}] &;
  If[Head[factors] === List,
   {constants, summand} = Times @@@ Flatten /@ Last@Reap[
        Sow[#, FreeQ[#, v]] & /@ factors,
        {True, False}];
   const`hold[Evaluate@constants] summand,
   expr]
  ]
const`release = const`hold[c_] :> c;
```

Example:

It's the second iterated sum that is the problem.  Below `s1` is the first iterated sum and we show the effect of `holdConstants` on it and its sum over `a`.

```
s1 = Sum[
   Binomial[m - 1, r] Binomial[r, a] Binomial[m - r - 1, b] z^(r + b) (-1)^(a + b + r + 1),
   {b, 0, m - r - 1}];
holdConstants[s1, a]
(*
(-1)^a Binomial[r, a] *
  const`hold[((-1)^r (1 - z)^(m - r) z^r Binomial[-1 + m, r])/(-1 + z)]
*)

Sum[s1, {a, 0, r}]
s2 = Sum[holdConstants[s1, a], {a, 0, r}] /. const`release
(*
0
((-1)^r (1 - z)^(m - r) z^r Binomial[-1 + m, r] KroneckerDelta[r])/(-1 + z)
*)
```

From here we can get the answer:

```
s3 = Sum[s2, {r, 0, m - 1}]
(*
   -(1 - z)^(-1 + m)
*)
```

#### General workaround

```
ClearAll[withHeldConstants];
SetAttributes[withHeldConstants, HoldAll];
withHeldConstants[Sum[summand_, iterators__]] :=
 Fold[Sum[holdConstants[#, First[#2]], #2] /. const`release &, 
  summand, Reverse@{iterators}]

withHeldConstants[
 Sum[
  Binomial[m - 1, r] Binomial[r, a] Binomial[m - r - 1, b] z^(r + b) (-1)^(a + b + r + 1),
  {r, 0, m - 1}, {a, 0, r}, {b, 0, m - r - 1}]]
Simplify[%]
(*
  (1 - z)^m/(-1 + z)
  -(1 - z)^(-1 + m)
*)
```

Braver folks may fiddle with the internals.  The function to hack for the OP's sum is `` Sum`IteratedUnivariateSummation ``.  It is straightforward to throw in `holdConstants` and `` const`release `` into its code.  One thing to beware of, aside from making a mistake and screwing up your kernel session, is that some sums are cached in `` Sum`SumParserDump`sumParserEvaluate ``.  It turns out that the OP's is.  The cached value is used in future calls.  For instance, if you ran the OP's code, you should find this among the definitions:

```
? Sum`SumParserDump`sumParserEvaluate
(*
  ...
  Sum`SumParserDump`sumParserEvaluate[(-1)^(1 + a + b + r) z^(b + r)
      Binomial[-1 + m, r] Binomial[-1 + m - r, b] Binomial[r, a], {{r, 
      0, -1 + m}, {a, 0, r}, {b, 0, -1 + m - r}}, {}] = 0
  ...
*)
```

You might need to `Unset` this definition when you fiddle with `` Sum`IteratedUnivariateSummation `` to see a change take effect.

I was unable to find a system call that resets the summation cache.  Normally, there would be no need for it.  I think `withHeldConstants` is a better alternative, but I wanted to record the location of the cache (at least in V9/10), so in the future, if others go trying to help `Sum` out, they can see if the cached results are thwarting their efforts.

#### Is it a bug?

Or just a limitation?  You'd think factoring out the constants, which is a first-year student technique, would not be hard to do.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it relates to convergence. Here are some experiments which may give a clue to that.

```
Sum[Binomial[m - r - 1, b] z^(r + b) (-1)^(a + b + r + 1), {b, 0, m - r - 1, 1}, GenerateConditions -> True]
ConditionalExpression[((-1)^(a + r) (1 - z)^(m - r) z^r)/(-1 + z), m - r \[Element] Integers && (z != 1 || Re[m - r] > 1) && m >= 1 + r]

Sum[Binomial[r, a] Sum[Binomial[m - r - 1, b] z^(r + b) (-1)^(a + b + r + 1), {b, 0, m - r - 1, 1}], {a, 0, r}, GenerateConditions -> True]
ConditionalExpression[0, r \[Element] Integers && r > 0]

Sum[Binomial[r, a] Sum[Binomial[m - r - 1, b] z^(r + b) (-1)^(a + b + r + 1), {b, 0, m - r - 1, 1}, GenerateConditions -> True], {a, 0, r}, GenerateConditions -> True]
ConditionalExpression[0, m - r \[Element] Integers && (z != 1 || Re[m - r] > 1) && m >= 1 + r && r \[Element] Integers && r > 0]

Sum[Binomial[m - 1, r] Binomial[r, a] Binomial[m - r - 1, b] z^(r + b) (-1)^(a + b + r + 1), {r, 0, m - 1, 1}, {a, 0, r, 1}, {b, 0, m - r - 1, 1}, GenerateConditions -> True]
0

Sum[ Binomial[r, a] (((-1)^(a + r) (1 - z)^(m - r) z^r)/(-1 + z)), {a, 0,   r}, GenerateConditions -> True]
ConditionalExpression[0, r \[Element] Integers && r > 0]

-(1 - z)^(m - r - 1) (-z)^r Sum[ Binomial[r, a] (-1)^a , {a, 0, r}, GenerateConditions -> True]
ConditionalExpression[-(1 - z)^(-1 + m - r) (-z)^r KroneckerDelta[r], r \[Element] Integers && r >= 0]
```